# how many person visited a specific web page?

Tags: javascript, client-server, counter

I know that I can see how many times someone opened a specific page in my website.

but What I want is to enter a web page URL like `www.example.com/page` from the user and see how many times this page was opened.

can I do this if the page was a PHP, HTML or even an URL for image or mp3 file.

What I'm trying to make is a web page that the user enters Different pages link and views how many times the page was opened.

Is that possible?

Comment: Do you want to track the WHOLE website, or just a specific page? If specific page, I could provide you with log file answer. There is also a way to do this with javascript and cookie, but that is unreliable, because the user could be blocking the cookies.

Comment: I want to track a specific page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first create a text file called userlog.txt and place it at the same directory, as the page you want to track. Then open up the tracked page (it has to be .php) and add following code:

```
<?php    
  $file = fopen("userlog.txt", "a") or die("There is a problem with opening the log file.");    
  $date = date("d.m.Y H:i:s");   
  $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];    
  $browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];    
  $txt = "Date: ". $date . "\nIP Adress: ". $ip . "\nUser's browser: " . $browser . "\n" . "\n";    
  fwrite($file, $txt);    
  fclose($file);    
  ?>
```

This will save each user's IP adress, browser and date/time off his visit to your userlog.txt file. After that you can count the entries. This can also be done by saving the same into the database, but you didn't specify if you can use database. Will edit if needed.

EDIT: I forgot to provide counting script as well. So create new file and call it for example "count.php" and write in the following code:

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents('userlog.txt');
$lines_arr = preg_split('/\n|\r/',$file);
$num_newlines = count($lines_arr);
$record = "4"; 
echo 'Number of lines in logfile: '.$num_newlines;
$unique = (int) ($num_newlines / $record);
echo '<br />Number of people who visited the page: '. $unique;
?>
```

Now if you open up your count.php in your browser, it should say how many people visited your specific page.